# CLion filling temp directory

Tags: clion

CLion has been generating multiple ~100M sized `preamble-*` files in the standard `/tmp` directory.

1. Any suggestions on how this can be disabled?
2. Alternatively any suggestions on how to change the default temp directory?

Comment: There is an open ticket for #2: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-15074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `preamble-*` files are created by Clang that is used by CLion.

To change the directory specify an environment variable `TMPDIR=/your/preferred/location` when running CLion.